# What do I set MONGO_OPLOG_URL to in Meteor Up?

Tags: deployment, meteor, compose-db, meteor-up

I have created a database and a user with oplog access in Compose.io.

The URI I get looks like this:

```
mongodb://<user>:<password>@lamppost.11.mongolayer.com:10022,lamppost.10.mongolayer.com:10024/cardmaker?replicaSet=set-<bunchOfDigits>
```

Knowing this, what do I set as `MONGO_URL` and `MONGO_OPLOG_URL` in `mup.json`?

There is literally no documentation on this. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say 
database name: mydatabase
username: user 
password: 123456

It will be looked like this:

```
 “MONGO_URL”: “mongodb://user:123456@candidate.11.mongolayer.com:10240,candidate.0.mongolayer.com:10240/mydatabase?replicaSet=set-0123456789″,
 “MONGO_OPLOG_URL”: “mongodb://user:123456@candidate.11.mongolayer.com:10240,candidate.0.mongolayer.com:10240/local?authSource=mydatabase”
```

Source: [Meteor Up Apps Deployment and Oplog-tailing](https://sensq.com/blog/meteor-up-apps-deployment-and-oplog-tailing)

Comment: I've always used `/local?authSource=mydatabase&replicaSet=set-0123456789` for the oplog. But curious if the replicaSet param is required for the oplog to continue to work after a step down?

Comment: @MikaelLirbank I forgot if the "/local?authSource=mydatabase&replicaSet=set-0123456789" will work. What's your result? But I'm 100% sure that "/local?authSource=mydatabase" is working fine.

Comment: It works well. I actually asked Compose.io support about the "?replicaSet" param for the MONGO_URL (not the OPLOG) a while ago and they said you actually don't need it at all. Most drivers are able to figure out the replica set without it. So I skipped it on both the URLs, but then there was a stepdown recently and my Meteor app had problems coping with it. So now I've added the replicaSet param for both MONGO_URL and MONGO_OPLOG_URL again.